# Asp.net cross domain cookies

Tags: c#, asp.net, cookies

I have got a requirement for getting cookies available for our domain as other team which works in another domain of our org will hit this url and as a response will get all the cookies available for our domain. 
I am fairly new to asp.net this is the below code for GetCookieInfo page.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string value= string.Empty;

    if (Request.Cookies["cookie1"] != null)
    {
        value= Request.Cookies["cookie1"].Value;
    }
    string message=""{\"message\":\"" + value+ "\"}";
    Response.Clear();
    Response.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
    Response.Write(message);
    Response.End();
}
```

I am getting the value in the browser but when I am hitting the URL in any other page and reading the response using stream, the message is not having cookie value even though cookie is present. What could be wrong with the above snippet?

Comment: If I understand correctly, another team sends a request to your page, and then the response should give them back all the cookies that were in their request?

Comment: Also, when you say "cookie is present" - did you determine this by observing the request in e.g. fiddler, or by debugging the code you posted, and seeing that "Request.Cookies["cookie1"] != null"?

Comment: They'll just call the url and we need to send back all the cookies available in our domain.   I have seen the cookie in the browser in cookies section.

Comment: OK, so you are running on www.A.com. When they issue a request to www.A.com, the only cookies in "Request.Cookies" in your code are the ones that they send. I assume they are making the request programmatically and not from a browser. So, if they set some cookies on the request, you can get those cookies the way you tried; I have to say that scenario does not make any sense. If they don't set any cookies, your code will return no cookies, which is expected. If you are trying to send "all the possible cookies my app ever sets" - this is not the way.

Comment: The cookies that you saw in the browser in the cookies section are the cookies that you have in your browser. They were put in your browser by your app when you first visited it. When the other team just fire off a request to your domain, their request will have no cookies unless they create some in their code and attach them to the request. So, either I completely misunderstood what you are trying to do, or you should read up on how cookies work.